# initializing a Guava ImmutableMap

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

Guava offers a nice shortcut for initializing a map.  However I get the following compiler error (Eclipse Indigo) when my map initializes to nine entries.

The method `of(K, V, K, V, K, V, K, V, K, V)` in the type `ImmutableMap` is not applicable for the arguments 
`(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)`

```
ImmutableMap<String,String> myMap = ImmutableMap.of(
        "key1", "value1", 
        "key2", "value2", 
        "key3", "value3", 
        "key4", "value4", 
        "key5", "value5", 
        "key6", "value6", 
        "key7", "value7", 
        "key8", "value8", 
        "key9", "value9"
        );
```

The message appears to say that

> An ImmutableMap has a maximum size of four pairs of key,value.

Obviously, this cannot be the case but I can't figure out what to do to increase the size of my initializer.

Can someone tell me what is missing?

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Notice that your error message only contains five `K, V` pairs, 10 arguments total. This is by design; the ImmutableMap class provides six different `of()` methods, accepting between zero and five key-value pairings. There is not an `of(...)` overload accepting a varags parameter because `K` and `V` can be different types.

You want an `ImmutableMap.Builder`:

```
ImmutableMap<String,String> myMap = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
    .put("key1", "value1") 
    .put("key2", "value2") 
    .put("key3", "value3") 
    .put("key4", "value4") 
    .put("key5", "value5") 
    .put("key6", "value6") 
    .put("key7", "value7") 
    .put("key8", "value8") 
    .put("key9", "value9")
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I decided to try Guava because I did not want to have to type all the 'puts' required by a standard map initializer.  So much for that idea!

Comment: @user903724: The main reason for using Guava here is the strong immutability, IMO.

Comment: That, or the slightly reduced memory consumption -- and the builder syntax is pretty fluent, as things go.

Comment: well, you may have multiple puts still, but they are now using fluent API, so no need to repeat `myMap` for each `.put`

Comment: Notice also how Jon's example code could be a `public static final` and it still works, no need for a helper method or `static{}` initializer!

Comment: As of Guava 31.0, you can actually use `.of` with up to 10 key/value pairs.

Answer (score 72):

if the map is short you can do:

```
ImmutableMap.of(key, value, key2, value2); // ...up to five k-v pairs
```

If it is longer then:

```
ImmutableMap.builder()
   .put(key, value)
   .put(key2, value2)
   // ...
   .build();
```

Comment: Apart from readability, you can use `ImmutableMap.of` static factory for up to five key value pairs. Then you have to use builder.

Comment: As of Guava 31.0, you can actually use `.of` with up to 10 key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a balance between capability and readability, you may combine both approaches:

```java
ImmutableMap<String,String> myMap = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
    .putAll(ImmutableMap.of(
        "key1", "value1", 
        "key2", "value2", 
        "key3", "value3", 
        "key4", "value4"));
    .putAll(ImmutableMap.of(
        "key5", "value5", 
        "key6", "value6", 
        "key7", "value7", 
        "key8", "value8", 
        "key9", "value9"));
    .build();
```

Whether or not this is a good idea, is something open to discussion.