# Guava ImmutableMap Builder syntax

Tags: java, guava, immutability

I've been using Guava's `ImmutableMap` with a `Builder` for awhile without giving much thought to how/why it works. I've been using the builder in the way described by the [Javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html):

```
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> WORD_TO_INT =
          new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer>()
              .put("one", 1)
              .put("two", 2)
              .put("three", 3)
              .build();
```

I've also seen examples [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9489463/772385) on SO of this syntax:

```
ImmutableMap<String,Integer> myMap = ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>builder()
    .put("one", 1) 
    .put("two", 2) 
    .put("three", 3) 
    .build();
```

Both seem to produce the exact same result.

A quick glance at the `ImmutableMap` [source](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.java) shows that the static `builder()` call in the 2nd example returns: `new Builder<K, V>()`

There doesn't appear to be any functional difference between the two methods.

Is there any difference under the hood? Any reason to prefer one or the other?

EDIT: Adding bytecode difference.

The bytecode generated is almost identical except for one line:

Method 1(`Builder<K,V>`):

```
static {};
     0  new com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder [12]
     3  dup
     4  invokespecial com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder() [14]
     7  ldc <String "key1"> [17]
     ........
```

Method 2:(`<K,V>builder()`)

```
static {};
     0  invokestatic com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.builder() : com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder [12]
     3  ldc <String "key1"> [18]
     ........
```

After that they're pretty much the same, the first line being different makes sense given the source differences, but I'm not sure why the first one calls `dup` and the second doesn't.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, they are identical. The reason for the first syntax is that it makes a nice one-liner.

The reason for the second syntax is the you might have a loop or other flow control, you may need to pass the `Builder` around.

For example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ImmutableList.Builder<Integer> lb = ImmutableList.builder();
    for (final String arg : args) {
        lb.add(Integer.parseInt(arg));
    }
}
```

And before you say it, yes a `FluentIterable` would probably be better in this case - but it's just an example.

Comment: Any idea why the `dup` shows up in the bytecode for the first one? I don't know enough about bytecode to know if that's typical or not.

Comment: @MagicMan if you look at the source code you will see that the methods are different - I'm not surprised that the bytecode is different. As to why it duplicates the value, I'm not sure.

Comment: Ahh, as long as there isn't any big difference I won't worry. Example makes it clear how I should be using it, thanks!

Comment: @MagicMan, you didn't provide full bytecode listing, but I believe that there is something like `invokespecial ...ImmutableMap$Builder.<init>()` after `dup` in the first example. This is exactly why `dup` is needed. In Java construction is two-phase process: first, new memory is allocated via `new`, and then a constructor method (`<init>`) is called on that memory. So `dup`ed stack element is consumed by the constructor.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Ahh, sorry, just edited and added that next line. You are correct, it was indeed `invokespecial....`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#builder%28%29), The generated builder is equivalent to the builder created by the ImmutableMap.Builder constructor.

It is a good practice to write such a method when applying the Builder pattern. This offers a fluent way to  use it and can be considered as a "syntactic sugar".