# Convert String[] str = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"} to map like {a=b, c=d, e=f} using java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the below code to implement the requirement, but  couldn't solve using stream , I'm not sure how to increment i in pipeline

```
String[] str = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"};
    Map<String, String> strMap = new HashMap<>();
    int i = 0;
    while(i< str.length && i +1 < str.length) {
        strMap.put(str[i],str[i+1]);
        i +=2;          
    }
```

Comment: Who said it's possible?

Comment: `i< str.length && i +1 < str.length` is redundant.

Comment: a for loop would be a lot clean I feel

Comment: If you can use Guava https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489384/initializing-a-guava-immutablemap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could use an `IntStream` to generate your indices (between `0` and the length of the array), filter out the odd indices and then use a `forEach` to populate the `strMap` - like,

```
String[] str = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
Map<String, String> strMap = new HashMap<>();
IntStream.range(0, str.length).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .forEach(i -> strMap.put(str[i], str[i + 1]));
System.out.println(strMap);
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
{a=b, c=d, e=f}
```

Comment: Thanks! solved my problem :)

Comment: Or `IntStream.range(0, str.length/2).map(i -> i*2)` which performs less operations, but on the other hand, won’t fail-fast when the array has an odd length.

Comment: @Holger OP's version doesn't fail on odd length either.

Comment: @shmosel: but I consider failing for malformed input a good thing.

Comment: @Holger I would generally agree, but it's hard to declare it malformed without more context.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with a simple stream of `str`, but you can mimic your loop with an index stream:

```
Map<String, String> strMap = IntStream.range(0, str.length - 1)
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> str[i], i -> str[i + 1]));
```

Comment: Thanks ! very helpful